# In what version of the HTML spec was <table> introduced

Tags: html

What version of the HTML spec was the  tag added?

Comment: Tables were already in `Mosaic` browser.

Comment: Regardless of whether `<table>` came after `<div>`, the CSS available couldn’t make the latter a suitable replacement for the former (assuming you’re talking about layout here).

Comment: My original argument was surrounding such things but this question was just about what version it was added in. I did a quick run through and had trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables were not in [HTML 2](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_toc.html) but were in [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#table).

(There were no, non-draft, specifications between those two versions, but [HTML 3.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/tables.html) also included tables.)

HTML 3.2 allows tables for layout but warns that there may be undesired side effects.

> can be used to markup tabular material or for layout purposes. Note that the latter role typically causes problems when rending to speech or to text only user agents

[HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.1) removed that option:

> should not be used purely as a means to layout document content

… and introduced support for stylesheets. (NB: The "divs vs tables" question is usually better expressed as "stylesheets vs tables").